# Strip // Comments From Files

Tags: text-processing, shell-script, php

What's the best way to strip all code **comments** in a given directory?  I'd like to strip out all `// ... EOL` **comments**, and `/* blah \*/` (or `/** ... \*/`) **comments** as well.

This is a PHP project, and I'd like to go a little further than what is outlined below, yet for security purposes rather than efficiency.

- [Zend Frameword: Documentation Class Loading](http://zendframework.com/manual/en/performance.classloading.html) - Strip require_once calls with find and set.

Comment: umm... how do you figure this is for security? removing comments will not enhance your security (unless you have a backdoor password in your comments, in which case nothing can help you)

Comment: @xenoterracide: The normal password would pose problem. Backdoor password might be deduced from code.

Comment: I'm handing the code over to another party.  It's a legal thing - that's all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[A quick google search returns a similar question at stackoverflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503871/best-way-to-automatically-remove-comments-from-php-code)

Comment: Using PHP's tokenizer itself is probably the only safe way; any way involving perl/awk/whatever is going to have problems with things like `$foo = "// you shouldn't be touching this!";`

Comment: Cool, will do some tests.  Appears to be what I need though.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This will do it in Perl:

```
//will delete all comments starting at the beginning of the line with //
perl -p -i -e "s#^//.*$##" <your php file>
//will delete all comments starting somewhere in a line with //
perl -p -i -e "s#^(.*)//.*$#\$1#" <your php file>
//will delete all comments starting somewhere in a line with /* or /**
perl -p -i -e "s#^(.*)/\*+.*$#\$1#" <your php file>
//will delete all comments starting at the beginning of the line with /* or /**
perl -p -i -e "s#^/\*+.*$##" <your php file>
```

These commands will not delete comments with multiple lines, like

```
/**
 *
 *
 */
```

It is possible to do this, but multi line regex are way more difficult.

There will also be solutions for awk, sed, python, ... But this should also do it.

Comment: Note that you are also going to have problems with strings that happen to have "//" inside them and likely other issues.